# express sessions do not work - new session upon every request

Tags: session, express, express-session

I use express-session to set up session management in the following way:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sessionTest');


app.listen(3000, function () {
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'justsomestuff',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {  } ,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})
}));

app.get('/first', function (req, res) {
    console.log('first');
    req.session.test = 'Tester';
    req.session.save();
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    res.send(req.sessionID);
}); 

app.get('/second', function (req, res) {
    console.log('second');
    if (req.session)
            console.log('session exists');
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    console.log(req.session.test);
    res.send(req.sessionID);
});
```

But a new session is established with a new session id every time I call /first or /second with

```
curl 127.0.0.1:3000/first
curl 127.0.0.1:3000/second
```

I use

```
"connect-mongo": "^1.2.1",
"express": "~4.13.4",
"express-session": "^1.14.0",
```

All sessions are in the mongo database as well.

It seems such a straight forward issue, but I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually sending back the session cookie in your `curl` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using curl. and curl don't support cookies implicitly. You have to pass the cookies value [explicitly via command](http://ask.metafilter.com/18923/How-do-you-handle-authentication-via-cookie-with-CURL). and also read the cookie when the server is trying to set etc..

**Why don't you test using browser.?**

or If you still want curl then  use -b and -c parameters like this.

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt
```

-b tells curl to store incoming cookies in cookies.txt and -c tells curl to embed all cookies from cookies.txt into this request.

Moreover Increase  cookies life  by adding expires field.

```
 app.use(session({
    secret: 'justsomestuff',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000)),
    cookie: {  } ,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})
 }));
```